# MaterialUI Text Field input getting 'undefined' values with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I am using React Hooks - useState and useEffect - to grab email/password form input from text fields provided by [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/) (specifically using the `BootstrapInput` under "Customized Inputs" on that page).

I have looked at similar StackOverflow questions about getting form values with React Hooks. Unfortunately, these solutions do not work for me as I believe my problem is with the Material UI Text Field I am using. In the other questions' solutions, the code uses a simple unstyled `input` tag.

I've tried putting the `handleChange` function in `InputField.js` - in this case, values.email and values.password are updated and printed correctly. However, validation (with the `validate` function) must be kept within `Form.js`. `handleChange` uses useState (`setValues`) to set the `values` variable, and `validate` uses `values`. Therefore `handleChange` must be kept in `Form.js` which is where I am having my problem.

Working demo here: https://glitch.com/~blue-peridot (click Show on the top-left corner, next to the project name and open your actual browser console to see output... ignore warnings from browser)

Firstly:

From Form.js - I expect values.email and values.password (lines 29-30) to be printed to console as they are entered in the `InputField`.

Actual output - `undefined`

Secondly:

`isSubmitting` is one step behind. I expect the value of `isSubmitting` to be set to True after clicking Login once (provided the input is valid). However, the value is not updated until after the second click.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your props through on your `InputField` component. Currently, you only have `label` as a prop.

e.g.

```
const InputField = ({
    label,
...others
}) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <FormControl className={classes.margin}>
                <InputLabel className={classes.label} shrink htmlFor="bootstrap-input">
                    {label}
                </InputLabel>
                <BootstrapInput {...others} />
            </FormControl>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Or you can only pass specific props through.

Answer (score 1):

A few things in Form.js:

1. Your `useEffect` hook is missing dependencies on both `isSubmitting` and `handleChange`.
2. You should be able to move `validate` outside of the component.
3. Optional, but: since you're passing `handleChange` and `handleSubmit` to other components, it will boost performance to wrap them in `useCallback` hooks, like

```
const handleChange = useCallback((event) => {
 event.persist();
 setValues(values => ({ ...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }));
}, [values]);

const handleSubmit = useCallback((event) => {
 if (event) event.preventDefault();
 setErrors(validate(values));
 setIsSubmitting(true);
}, [values]);
```

If you have ESLint setup or can, eslint-plugin-react-hooks helps to catch these issues.